# Manipulate previous item inside Array.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm transforming my array with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and if the current item matches some conditions, I want to change its previous item.

The code below seems not working, how do I do it without a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop?

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var res = nums.map((item, index, array) => {
  if (item > 3) {
    array[index - 1] += 1;
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(res); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], I want [1, 2, 4, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reducer

```js
var res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  .reduce((reduced, item, i) => {
     i && (reduced[i-1] += item > 3 ? 1 : 0);
     return [...reduced, item];
   }, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: double-click 666

Answer (score 1):

Arrays that are in the process of being created from `.map` can't be referenced like that. Instead, create the array *outside* of the `forEach`, and push to / assign to it:

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const newArr = [];
nums.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item > 3) newArr[index - 1] += 1;
  newArr.push(item);
});

console.log(newArr); // I want [1, 2, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I would like to add that `.map()` is what's called an _out-of-place_ algorithm, which means that the output array is not the same reference as the input `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this answer is only here because I feel whenever somebody asks "how do I do X without a for loop", I feel there should at least be *one* recursive solution between all the maps and reduces :)

> how do I do it without a for loop?

If you don't care much about performance or the risk of blowing the stack, you can go with a recursive function!

Here's an example:

- Destructure your array into `first`, `second` and the rest
- If `first` is empty, we've reached the end of our computation and return the result
- If `first` is not empty, we can compare it to `second` to determine its value. We add the value to our result and recurse:
- Call the function again, but now with `[second, ...rest]` and passing along our result

```js
const input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
const Empty = Symbol();

const incIfBt3 = 
  ([first = Empty, second, ...rest], result = []) =>
    first === Empty
      ? result
      : incIfBt3(
          [second, ...rest],
          [...result, first + (second > 3)]
        );
        
        
console.log(incIfBt3(input));
```

Comment: Disclaimer:  Your idea is cool and interesting, but I think recursive code is harder to understand sometimes

Comment: Agreed! If you hadn’t already received so many good answers I wouldn’t have posted this one. I upvoted the answer by JLRishe because that’s the one I’d actually use in shared/production code 

Answer (score 0):

You can look ahead instead of trying to look behind:

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var res = nums.map((item, index, array) => {
  if (array[index + 1] > 3) {
    item += 1;
  }
  return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change the *previous* item, you can use the `array` parameter to look at the *next* item and return a value for the *current* item accordingly:

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var res = nums.map((item, index, array) => item + (array[index + 1] > 3 ? 1 : 0));

console.log(res); // [1, 2, 4, 5, 5]
```

You can also take advantage of the fact that the numeric value of a boolean is either 1 or 0 to eliminate the conditional expression:

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var res = nums.map((item, index, array) => item + (array[index + 1] > 3));

console.log(res); // [1, 2, 4, 5, 5]
```

Comment: There's a mass downvoter on the loose! Show yourself!